# No table is displaying in R markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm trying to create a table in R markdown.

I found this website which outlines how to create formatted tables. [website](http://reate%20Awesome%20HTML%20Table%20with%20knitr::kable%20and%20kableExtra)

The code in my R notebook file is:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---
```{r, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kable(dt)
```
````

Any ideas on why does this code does not work?

Comment: I tested your code, and I do see a table in the output. Everything look alright to me.

Comment: Same for me. It works OK and generates HTML.

Comment: Oh my reply didn't get posed. I figured out if you run the block of code it displays correctly. Also, noted if their is an error somewhere in the markdown file it might stop it from updating.